# How to find string path to fetch files from assests like SDCard/

Tags: java, android, file, path, sd-card

I need to give PathtToFile in String format in a method. I am able to access a file stored in Sdcard by using "/sdcard/2012suppfishregs.pdf". But How can i access a file which is stored in asset folder So i could access it from assets folder. I tried with "file:///android_asset/2012suppfishregs.pdf" but it's occurring exception that path not found everytime.

Can anybody tell me how can i find the path in string format to access this file So it will work in place of Sdcard path as mentioned above.

Thanks. Please help me.

Comment: which asset folder are you talking about. The asset folder in the source of your app(just like src, res etc.) or you have a folder named asset in your sdcard

Comment: yes, Rohit. for same.

Comment: for that link provided by Desu is sufficient right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below link for accessing files stored from asset folder.

https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/